# Google Maps API Polyline animation speed on line length

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a map with multiple Polylines with a animation to make it look like they are moving towards something (almost like a progress-bar).

I looked at this example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate

So I'm now doing this:

```
const lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    scale: 2,
};

const circlesLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [arrival, departure],
    strokeColor: color,
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    icons: [{
        icon: lineSymbol,
        offset: '100%',
        repeat: '20px',
    }],
    map,
});

let count = 0;
this.lineAnimation = setInterval(() => {
    count++;

    const icons = circlesLine.get('icons');
    icons[0].offset = count + '%';
    circlesLine.set('icons', icons);
}, 20);
```

So I'm using the offset to tween the line

Only thing I can't figure out is how to make the speed the same for every line. Now the longer the line the faster the animation goes, which makes sense but I don't know how to make a calculation depending on the length.

Hope someone can help me out, thnx!

Comment: The `setInterval` is what sets the update time.  The `(count / 3) + '%'` sets the distance moved.  How have you tried to change those based on your lines?

Comment: @geocodezip yes, but that does not solve my problem. The animation on the line moves faster because I'm using the offset, so I have to find a way to figure out how to make that calculation depending on the length of the line or, don't use offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking way to complicated, the solution was really simple.

I ended up just change the offset to 'px' instead of '%'.

```
let count = 0;
this.lineAnimation = setInterval(() => {
    count++;

    const icons = circlesLine.get('icons');
    icons[0].offset = count + 'px';
    circlesLine.set('icons', icons);
}, 20);
```

Hope this helps someone else.